# GUI Errrant "Failed Transcation"

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, remote-node, stagenet

I can see a Stagnet transaction from one of my wallets to another has succeed using https://stagenet.xmrchain.net, (with over 11 confirmation). but neither of my GUI wallets say it went through -- in fact the sending wallet says the transaction has failed.

I'm connected to the remote node: monero-stagenet.exan.tech over port 3801.

I've closed and re-opened the GUI wallets, but the discrepancy remains.

Comment: I think the problem is that although my daemon is synchronized, my wallet synchronization progress bar is still at 0.

Comment: Can you try restoring the stagenet wallet from the mnemonic seed with a proper restore height?

Answer (score 0):

Are you now using a remote node or your local node?

> I'm connected to the remote node: monero-stagenet.exan.tech over port 3801.
> ... although my daemon is synchronized ...

monero-stagenet.exan.tech RPC port is **38081** not **3801**!
http://monero-stagenet.exan.tech:38081/get_info

Maybe the remote node was offline or has banned your wallet/IP. Some more [open stagenet nodes](https://monero.fail/?nettype=stagenet)